# About "with-input-from-file" command on Scheme

Tags: scheme

How do I call the content of a file in an interpreter of Scheme working on the terminal of Ubuntu?

I am trying to make use of some data included into a text file and "with-input-from-file" is not working, even spelling the exact direction of that file. I would like to call that content without having to execute the file first.

Comment: The code does not make sense. `/home/.../file` is a variable since it is not quoted. eg it is assumed to be defined by you at an earlier point and since you do `cdr` of it it should be a pair like `(cons 4 5)`. Then the expression would work and become `5`.  `with-input-from-file` will replace stdin with the contents of the file name in the first argument for the duration og the function in the second. thus `(read-char)` will read the char from the file instead of stdin. You are probably looking for `(load "path/to/file")`?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but maybe you are looking for `load`? ie `(load "/home/.../file.scm")`. It will read and evaluate (call) content of a file.

Comment: What format is the data in the text file? Is it Scheme code, S-expressions, Comma-separated values, Tab-separated values, Json? Or do you just want one string for the whole value?

Comment: Also, which variant of scheme are you using? Is it R6RS-compatible, R5RS-compatible, or?

Comment: I do not understand, I'm sorry. I have been asked to make use of "with-input-from-file" to use that data as an input for a simple procedure. Is it possible to do it on the ubuntu terminal? How? Alex Knauth, I am using Racket 7.0 and make use of a R5RS manual.

Comment: Downvote. Why? Am I supposed to know everything? The manuals say nothing about using "with-input-from-a-file" over the terminal...

Comment: Can you update your question with a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried and what's going wrong with it?

Comment: An `in-port` is not a cons pair. It is an input port. You can use functions like `read`, `read-char`, `get-line`, `get-string-n`, or `get-string-all` on it, not `cdr`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I could have found an answer to my problem: is it possible that "with-input-from-file" is not available to my scheme interpreter in the Ubuntu terminal? That could be the case according to what can be read in page 134 of "The Scheme Programming Language." 2nd ed. R. Kent Dybvig: with-input-from-file is in the Revised Report but not the ANSI/IEEE standard together with what is said in: manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/scm.1.html Can that be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Scheme interpreter you're using is R6RS-compatible, you can use [`with-input-from-file`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_796) from the [io simple](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_sec_8.3) library like this:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs io simple))

(with-input-from-file "path/to/file.txt"
  (lambda ()
    ;; do the reading using the current input port
    ....))
```

Notice how there are two arguments:

- the path to the file
- a `lambda ()` with no arguments that must do the reading

Alternatively, you can use [`call-with-input-file`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_776), also from the [io simple](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_sec_8.3) library:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs io simple))

(call-with-input-file "path/to/file.txt"
  (lambda (in-port)
    ;; do the reading using `in-port` explicitly
    ....))
```

Notice how there are two arguments:

- the path to the file
- a `lambda (in-port)` with one argument that must do the reading, using `in-port` as an input port

To actually do the reading once you have the input port, you can use functions like `read`, `read-char`, `get-string-n`, `get-string-all`, `get-line`, or `get-datum`. Which one you should use depends on the format of the data in the text file. The simplest one that reads the whole file is [`get-string-all`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_704) from the io-ports library:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs io ports)
        (rnrs io simple))

(call-with-input-file "path/to/file.txt"
  (lambda (in-port)
    ;; do the reading using `in-port` explicitly
    (get-string-all in-port)))
```

And it is worth noting that if this is your final program it can be simplified to:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs io ports)
        (rnrs io simple))

(call-with-input-file "path/to/file.txt" get-string-all)
```

Comment: I do not see the point yet. Can I call the file as an input? I mean: (function (with-input-from-file "path/to/file.txt")). It is asking two arguments rather than one.

Comment: In both of my examples I am passing two arguments. The first argument is the "path/to/file.txt", and the second argument is a `lambda`.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have: "; with-input-from-file: contract violation
;   expected: (-> any)"

Comment: Can you update your question with a Minimal Complete example of what you've tried and what's going wrong with it?